# htaccess rewrite if no rewrite was provided

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

First off I'm not an expert in htaccess stuff, but i try to accomplish the following for some SEO fixes.

When the url is loaded, without any params/rewrite it should get some data attached before it continues.

For example:

> `http://www.domain.com` >>> `http://www.domain.com/en/`

I thought the rewrite was right like this, but didn't work (500)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(en|nl|de|etc)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/ [L,R=301]
```

#### added

```
RewriteRule ^(/?[^/]+) /index.php?rewrite=1 [L] # tell php we got a rewrite
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/en/ [NC]
```

Comment: Tried it and it got me to just the domain.com. If i add another rule like <code>RewriteRule ^(/?[^/]+) /index.php?rewrite=1 [L]</code> i'll get the 500 again..